# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found, what is wrong?

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn JAVA and I have a very simple task to do but I have a problem

In Eclipse it's work fine, but in IDEONE is error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>    at Main.main(Main.java:9)

There is my code:

```
    Scanner tek=new Scanner(System.in);
    String t2=tek.nextLine();
    int t=Integer.parseInt(t2);
    int tablica1[]= new int[t];
    if(t>=1 && t<=100)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
        {
            String ciag=tek.nextLine();
            String tablica[]=ciag.split(" ");
            int x=Integer.parseInt(tablica[1]);
            int y=Integer.parseInt(tablica[2]);
            if(tablica[0].equals("+"))
            {
                tablica1[i]=x+y;
            } else if(tablica[0].equals("-"))
            {
                tablica1[i]=x-y;
            } else if(tablica[0].equals("*"))
            {
                tablica1[i]=x*y;
            } else if(tablica[0].equals("/"))
            {
                tablica1[i]=x/y;
            } else if(tablica[0].equals("%"))
            {
                tablica1[i]=x%y;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tablica1[i]);
        }
    }
```

I know I can declare

`int t=tek.nextInt();` in start but when I do this I have more errors;p

Could you tell me, please what's wrong with my code?

Can you explain this step-by-step?

I have this same error in 2 programs; in the other programs I declare `tek.nextLine();` before for loop and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing `tek.nextLine()`, in your for loop, you need to check if `Scanner` has `nextToken`

```
while (tek.hasNext())
```

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: so how it should look like?
When i add this line in my code a have error... i don't understand why in Eclipse it working perfectly, but in IDEONE no...
thank for reply

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it isn't actually your code making the error, but IDEONE. If it works in Eclipse there's no other reason I can think of that would stop it from working in another IDE, unless of course you are using a different Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String ciag=tek.nextLine();
    String tablica[]=ciag.split(" ");
    int x=Integer.parseInt(tablica[1]);
    int y=Integer.parseInt(tablica[2]);
```

How do you know there are 3 tokens in ciag? How do you know that the inputs 1 and 2 are integers ? (You will get an Exception if the user enters "- 5 x")

Comment: I have task where first tokken is mathematical sign and another 2 are Integers, which will be performed the operation indicated in 1 tokken;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running this code using command prompt? and see what errors are you getting. IDE doesn't generate any error.